# RViz - showing [0] points from [0] messages - Gazebo lidar issue

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros2, rviz, gazebo-ignition

I created a robot model with lidar in .sdf file, I'm using Ignition (Gazebo) for simulation:

```xml
<?xml version="1" ?>
<sdf version="1.8">
    <world name="roomba_world">

        [plugins]

        [ground model]

        [wall model]

        <model name='roomba' canonical_link='chassis'>            
            <pose relative_to='world'>0 0 0.3 0 0 0</pose>
            [chassis with IMU sensor link]

            <link name='lidar'>
                <pose relative_to='chassis'>0.2 0 0.065 0 0 0</pose>
                <inertial>
                    <mass>1</mass>
                    <inertia>
                        <ixx>0.095329</ixx>
                        <ixy>0</ixy>
                        <ixz>0</ixz>
                        <iyy>0.381317</iyy>
                        <iyz>0</iyz>
                        <izz>0.476646</izz>
                    </inertia>
                </inertial>
                <visual name='visual'>
                    <geometry>
                        <cylinder>
                            <radius>0.07</radius>
                            <length>0.04</length>
                        </cylinder>
                    </geometry>
                  <material>
                        <ambient>0.2 0.2 0.2 1</ambient>
                        <diffuse>0.2 0.2 0.2 1</diffuse>
                        <specular>0.2 0.2 0.2 1</specular>
                    </material>
                </visual>
                <collision name='collision'>
                    <geometry>
                        <cylinder>
                            <radius>0.07</radius>
                            <length>0.03</length>
                        </cylinder>
                    </geometry>
                </collision>
                <sensor name='gpu_lidar' type='gpu_lidar'>"
                    <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
                    <topic>lidar</topic>
                    <update_rate>15</update_rate>
                    <ray>
                        <scan>
                            <horizontal>
                                <samples>270</samples>
                                <resolution>1</resolution>
                                <min_angle>-2.356194</min_angle>
                                <max_angle>2.356194</max_angle>
                            </horizontal>
                            <vertical>
                                <samples>1</samples>
                                <resolution>0.01</resolution>
                                <min_angle>0</min_angle>
                                <max_angle>0</max_angle>
                            </vertical>
                        </scan>
                        <range>
                            <min>0.04</min>
                            <max>4</max>
                            <resolution>0.01</resolution>
                        </range>
                    </ray>
                    <always_on>1</always_on>
                    <visualize>true</visualize>
                </sensor>
            </link>

            [wheels links]

            <joint name='lidar_joint' type='fixed'>
                <parent>chassis</parent>
                <child>lidar</child>
            </joint>

            [wheels joints]

            <plugin filename="libignition-gazebo-diff-drive-system.so" name="ignition::gazebo::systems::DiffDrive">
                <left_joint>left_wheel_joint</left_joint>
                <right_joint>right_wheel_joint</right_joint>
                <wheel_separation>0.55</wheel_separation>
                <wheel_radius>0.1</wheel_radius>
                <odom_publish_frequency>1</odom_publish_frequency>
                <topic>cmd_vel</topic>
            </plugin>
        </model>
    </world>
</sdf>
```

Simulation creates topics:

```
klaudiusz@klaudiusz:~/ros_roomba$ ros2 topic list
/clicked_point
/client_count
/cmd_vel
/connected_clients
/goal_pose
/imu
/initialpose
/lidar
/lidar/points
/model/roomba/tf
/parameter_events
/rosout
/tf
/tf_static
```

I'm bridging some topics to ROS2 Humble:

```
klaudiusz@klaudiusz:~/ros_roomba$ ros2 topic list
/clicked_point
/client_count
/cmd_vel
/connected_clients
/goal_pose
/imu
/initialpose
/lidar
/lidar/points
/model/roomba/tf
/parameter_events
/rosout
/tf
/tf_static
```

RViz2 needs static frame to run, so I'm publishing it with ROS2 node:

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include "geometry_msgs/msg/transform_stamped.hpp"
#include "tf2_msgs/msg/tf_message.hpp"
#include "tf2_ros/transform_broadcaster.h"


class FramePublisher : public rclcpp::Node {
public:
  FramePublisher() : Node("frame_publisher") {
    // Create transform broadcaster
    tf_broadcaster = std::make_unique<tf2_ros::TransformBroadcaster>(*this);

    // Create subscription on simulation tf topic
    tf_sub = this->create_subscription<tf2_msgs::msg::TFMessage>("/model/roomba/tf", 10, std::bind(&FramePublisher::handlePose, this, std::placeholders::_1));
  }

private:
  void handlePose(const std::shared_ptr<tf2_msgs::msg::TFMessage> msg) {
    // Pass tf message from simulation 
    geometry_msgs::msg::TransformStamped transform_msg;

    transform_msg.header.stamp = this->get_clock()->now();
    transform_msg.header.frame_id = "world";
    transform_msg.child_frame_id = "roomba_frame";
    transform_msg.transform.translation.x = msg->transforms.data()->transform.translation.x;
    transform_msg.transform.translation.y = msg->transforms.data()->transform.translation.y;
    transform_msg.transform.translation.z = msg->transforms.data()->transform.translation.z;
    transform_msg.transform.rotation.x = msg->transforms.data()->transform.rotation.x;
    transform_msg.transform.rotation.y = msg->transforms.data()->transform.rotation.y;
    transform_msg.transform.rotation.z = msg->transforms.data()->transform.rotation.z;
    transform_msg.transform.rotation.w = msg->transforms.data()->transform.rotation.w;
    
    tf_broadcaster->sendTransform(transform_msg);
  }
  // Variables
  rclcpp::Subscription<tf2_msgs::msg::TFMessage>::SharedPtr tf_sub;
  std::unique_ptr<tf2_ros::TransformBroadcaster> tf_broadcaster;
};


int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
  rclcpp::spin(std::make_shared<FramePublisher>());
  rclcpp::shutdown();
  return 0;
}
```

Then, in Rviz2 I can choose static frame (roomba or world) and lidar topic:
[image: rviz settings]
But lidar beam doesn't show.
Lidar topic echo:

```
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 3
    nanosec: 235000000
  frame_id: roomba/lidar/gpu_lidar
angle_min: -2.356194019317627
angle_max: 2.356194019317627
angle_increment: 0.017518170177936554
time_increment: 0.0
scan_time: 0.0
range_min: 0.03999999910593033
range_max: 4.0
ranges:
- .inf
- 2.9525601863861084
- '...'
intensities:
- 0.0
- '...'
```

It's first complicated ROS project of mine, I'm not experienced so some things may be faulty. Can you help me find the reason why RViz doesn't accept my lidar topic? All 'intensities' are equal to 0.0.

I'm alse getting this message in the terminal:

```
Message Filter dropping message: frame 'roomba/lidar/gpu_lidar' at time 17.887 for reason 'discarding message because the queue is full'
```

I searched many other questions and I tried many RViz configurations.

Edit:
I built my robot in urdf format entirely, based at sdf one. I used

```
ros2 launch urdf_tutorial display.launch.py model:=`ros2 pkg prefix --share urdf_tutorial`/urdf/01-myfirst.urdf
```

to run robot_state_publisher. I have static frame for every link of my robot in Rviz. I ran

```
ros2 run tf2_tools view_frames
```

and here is the result:
[image]
The issue stays the same.

Comment: Did you check that the the frame_id of the laser `roomba/lidar/gpu_lidar` has a tf ?

you can run

```bash
ros2 run tf2_tools view_frames
```
The open the generated pdf, then check that this frame_id is available and connected

if this is not working then you need to launch the `robot_state_publisher`

Comment: I geuss it's working, look at the screen shot at the end of my question.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the tf image, you don't have transformation between the `roomba` frame_id and the `roomba/lidar/gpu_lidar` frame_id.

You should launch `robot_state_publisher` to publish all the robot tf.

```bash
ros run robot_state_publisher robot_state_publisher --ros-args -p robot_description:="<string with robot description>"
```

You can check for example this [file](https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot4/blob/humble/turtlebot4_description/launch/robot_description.launch.py) if you want to learn how to launch robot_description from a launch file.

Try to launch this node and share again your tf, then we can continue debugging your issue

Comment: Can you look at my updated question?